# Is there a more direct approach to time series correlation in the Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, pandas, google-earth-engine-python-api

I want to know how the time attributes of `ee.Image` and `ee.ImageCollection`objects exist in Google Earth Engine. I am looking for whether there are operations on time series in GEE, such as resampling, sliding window, etc. The bigger thing is to know if the `Python Api` can be combined with other libraries, such as pandas.

Answer (score 1):

You can perform time series analysis in Earth Engine.  Please see [this reference](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials#time-series-analysis) or [this code lab](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1mNIRB90jwLuASO1JYas1kuOXCLbOoy1Z4NlV1qIXM10/edit#heading=h.6f09b65xgrdt).

The second part of your question is more complicated.  Images and collections are server objects ([reference](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server), [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorial_js_02)).  You can not mix them with third party libraries (such as pandas), although it is possible to request the data from Earth Engine and put it into a dataframe.  For example, see [this notebook](https://github.com/google/earthengine-community/blob/6a074480991148f56ef778049841995743c1cf81/tutorials/time-series-visualization-with-altair/tutorial.ipynb), although it's still in review, so use with caution.

Comment: Thanks for you answer!